# How to extract attribute value from XML in SQL Server 2019 (v15)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I would need to extract elements from this XML into a tabular form, but I can't seem to get my head around how this would work on SQL Server via something like XQuery.

I have all the data in a temporary table called "#1" and the XML itself lies in a field called "Message" in that temporary table. How can I extract the values "Test1" and "2,2 %" into separate fields  called "W08003" and "W1A081", respectively? The attribute names and the schema will remain the same over time? I would also need to do this on a row by row basis for each XML in the current temporary table.

```
<Individual xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Content>
    <status xmlns:d3p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d3p1:result="ok" />
    <uc xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/">
      <xmlReply>
        <reports xmlns:d5p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d5p1:lang="eng">
          <d5p1:report d5p1:id="7605089247" d5p1:name="Test1 Test2" d5p1:styp="K39" d5p1:index="0">
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W080" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="ID particulars">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W08001">9760508923</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W08002">7605089277</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W08003">Test1</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W08004">Test2</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W1A0" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="UC RPB">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W1A003">000000000000000022</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W1A081">2,2 %</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W1A082">2,18839</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
          </d5p1:report>
        </reports>
      </xmlReply>
    </uc>
  </Content>
</Individual>
```

Current SQL code:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS ns,'http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS d5p1)
SELECT ok.*
    ,X.g.value('(@d5p1:id)','varchar(20)') AS id
    ,X.g.value('(text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS term
into #2
FROM #1 as ok
CROSS APPLY(ok.[Message].nodes('Individual/Content/ns:uc/ns:xmlReply/ns:reports/ns:report/ns:group/ns:term') X(g)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What are the *actual* results you are after here?

Comment: I would like to derive "Test1", "Test2" and "2,2 %" as new columns into an existing table, given that the XML is included as a column in my current temp table.

Comment: Please edit your original question, and add ##1-4 from my comment above.

Comment: How stable is the XML that you're working with - is it likely to change from one iteration to another, or will its schema remain consistent and predictable?

Comment: The attribute names and schema will remain the same over time!

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 18? We're only on SQL Server 15 (2019) at the moment, with version 16 coming out this year (2022). Version 18 won't be out for some years yet (probably 2026-2028), and likely isn't even in development,

Comment: Sorry, the version I use is 15! Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no expected results, perhaps this is enough to get you started.

As you define a default namespace only once you get to  `status`, you can't use a `DEFAULT` namespace in `XMLNAMESPACES`, so I name it `ns` and reference that instead. This gives you the value of all the `term`s and their `id` attribute:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<Individual xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Content>
        <status xmlns:d3p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d3p1:result="ok" />
        <uc xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/">
            <xmlReply>
                <reports xmlns:d5p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d5p1:lang="eng">
                    <report d5p1:id="7605089247" d5p1:name="Test1 Test2" d5p1:styp="K39" d5p1:index="0">
                        <group d5p1:id="W080" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="ID particulars">
                            <term d5p1:id="W08001">9760508923</term>
                            <term d5p1:id="W08002">7605089277</term>
                            <term d5p1:id="W08003">Test1</term>
                            <term d5p1:id="W08004">Test2</term>
                        </group>
                        <group d5p1:id="W1A0" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="UC RPB">
                            <term d5p1:id="W1A003">000000000000000022</term>
                            <term d5p1:id="W1A081">2,2 %</term>
                            <term d5p1:id="W1A082">2,18839</term>
                        </group>
                    </report>
                </reports>
            </xmlReply>
        </uc>
    </Content>
</Individual>';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS ns,'http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS d5p1)
SELECT X.g.value('(@d5p1:id)','varchar(20)') AS id,
       X.g.value('(text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS term
FROM @XML.nodes('Individual/Content/ns:uc/ns:xmlReply/ns:reports/ns:report/ns:group/ns:term') X(g);
```

*I note that the XML has been changed since the initial version I used to write this answer. This answer has not been (read "won't be") adjusted for that.*

Comment: The XML is located inside a temporary table called "#1". This temporary table has a field called "Message", which contains that full XML itself.

Comment: Then you use would `nodes` against that column instead of a variable in your `FROM`, @PaganScientist . `CROSS APPLY YourAlias.YourColumn.nodes...`

Comment: Could you provide code example @Larnu?

Comment: `SELECT... FROM dbo.YourTable YT CROSS APPLY YT.YourColumn.nodes...` @PaganScientist .

Comment: I reformated the start post and included my SQL attempt. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a44ef83bd45349b119084bed0a6684af) @PaganScientist .

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I had a problem with case sensitivity in one of the letters in the path!

Comment: Yes, XQuery is case sensitive, @PaganScientist , even if you are using a case insensitive collation. Trying to reference an element `NAme` would return `NULL` if it is actually called `Name`.